# Cordova adb: Command failed with exit code EACCES

Tags: android, cordova

I've been stock this problem for a while.
My OSX is `Catalina 10.15.3`
VSCode is `1.42.1`
cordova version 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
cordova platform

```
android 8.1.0
ios 5.1.1
```

And when I try to run my project on android phone it should be like this:

```
cordova run android
```

Here's what I've got:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
43 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 41 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
/Users/myUserName/docs/projectName/projectName_I/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myUserName/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
adb: Command failed with exit code EACCES
```

It should be a simple question because it is all about permission things, but I've tried:

```
sudo chmod 777
chmod -R 777
chmod a+x
```

Here are one of those command excuted situation

```
myUserName@myMacBook-Pro cordova % sudo chmod 777 /Users/myUserName/docs/projectName/projectName_I/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Password:
myUserName@myMacBook-Pro cordova %
```

but still no luck, no error message, no any hint, nothing.
Did anyone know what kind of situation is this?
Thanks for your reply.